# How to execute javascript in Neutronium library?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, neutronium

I'm a hybrid app WPF + Neutronium (html, css, javascript),

When occurs SelectionChanged event in the ListBox WPF component, the csharp calls codebehind like:

```
private void searchList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

Inside this method I need to send a javascript command to Neutronium (WPF:HTMLViewControl).

But I don't found anyone javascript execute command in neutronium HTMLViewControl component.

How I make it?

Neutronium: https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Neutronium

Answer (score 3):

Neutronium philosophy is to use MVVVM pattern as a communication between JS and C#.

As such, the best way to react to searchList_SelectionChanged is to update a view model property that will trigger changes in the HTML side.

Pseudo code using Vue:
C#:

```
private void searchList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   vm.Selected = selected;
}
```

Vm:

```
public class MainVm
{
    private SelectedObject _Selected ;
    public SelectedObject Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected ; }
        set 
        { 
           _Selected = value; 
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
        }
    }
//...
}
```

Vue template:

```
<component :element:="viewModel.Selected ">
</component >
```

Neutronium will take care of all the communication here.

If you need something more specific you can even use a [Vue.js watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) on the selected element.

I will recomend you to take a look at: https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/Neutronium.SPA.Demo, https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/CodeDependencyScanner
and https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Music.Cover.Finder that are good example of Neutronium usage.

Comment: The example codegravity doesn't seem to exist any more, may be https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/NeutroniumDemo now